# The probability that one, two or three lights are on in any given time increment is the steady state vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

As I was self studying, I came accross this exercise that made me think a lot about what a steady-state vector is. Wouldn't the probabilities change at each time increment with the following transition matrix?

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/3 & 2/3 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\
$$

Does anyone understand the question being asked below? Do we just sit down and observe the process for like infinity, hence just computing the steady state vector?

> There are three spotlights flickering in a parking lot. Observations
> of the lights are made in regular increments. Given that one of the
> lights is on, there is a 50–50 chance either two or three lights will
> be on in the next time increment. Given two lights are on, there is a
> 2 in 3 chance two lights will remain on in the next time increment,
> otherwise one light will be on. If there are three lights on, in the
> next time increment there is always one light on.
> Find the probability that one, two or three lights are on in any given time increment.

Comment: I think the question is about the limiting distribution as n → ∞. If so, it may help to find eigenvectors of the transition matrix.

Comment: @DanAsimov That's what I thought but the "on in any given time increment" is a bit confusing as probabilities on any time increment will depend on past states assuming a MC model. Solving for (I-P)X=0 or rather computing the eigen vector should be the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a reasonable interpretation. Alternatively, maybe you could express your answer in terms of some initial probability vector $v$. In which case, the probabilities would be $vP^n$, for the $n$-th time increment.

Comment: what would v be in this case? 
would you make assumptions?

Comment: the initial probability vector. for example, if we knew for a fact that we start with 2 lights on, then v=(0,1,0), etc